# get the value of an input in laravel for a route

Tags: php, laravel

**i have an input called id and i want to specify the button path for that id example:**

> in my blade file

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <lable for="">ID:</lable><br/>
    <input type="text" name="id"  placeholder="Enter the product name" required><br/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="location.href='/produtos/editar/{{$id}}';" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
      </div>
```

> Now my controler.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $produto=Produto::findOrFail($id);
    $produto->update([
        'id'=>$request->id,
    'Nome'=>$request->nome,
    'custo'=>$request->custo,
    'preco'=>$request->preco,
    'quantidade'=>$request->quantidade,
    'Marca'=>$request->marcas,
      'Voltagem'=>$request->Voltagem,
      'Descricao'=>$request->Descricao,
    ]);
    return " Produto Atualizado com Sucesso!";
}
```

> now in routes file

```
Route::get('/produtos/editar/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProdutosController@edit');
Route::post('/produtos/editar/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProdutosController@update')->name('alterar_produto');
```

Being able to get the input value and put it along the route to the file

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: You need to pass ID to view.

Comment: @OMiShah i can I can't get the input value and pass it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set post method for update data. You have onclick action on submit button, but your route method is POST. Therefore, your update procedure doesn't work. You need to change code with  element, like that:

```
<form action="/produtos/editar/<?=$id?>" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <lable for="">ID:</lable>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter the product name" required><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "Undefined variable $id"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use laravel form for that

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('App\Http\Controllers\ProdutosController@update', $produto->id), 'method' => 'POST')) }}

  <div class="modal-body">
   <lable for="">ID:</lable><br/>
   <input type="text" name="id"  placeholder="Enter the product name" required> 
   <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
  </div>

 {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: ``['action' => ['ProdutosController@update', $id], 'method' => 'POST']`` :p

Comment: @Lenna Patel "Class not found"

Comment: try using full path like `App\Http\Controllers\ProdutosController@update`

Comment: @LeenaPatel now say" Undefined variable $id"

Comment: then your variable is not defined. from where are you getting id?

Comment: from my main.blade input ,and my controller product

Comment: did you passed id in blade context? share your controller edit function

Comment: public function edit($id){
    $produto=Produto::findOrFail($id);
   return view('produtos.edit',['produto'=>$produto]);
}

Comment: @LeenaPatel here

Comment: use `$produto->id` instead of `$id`

Comment: @LeenaPatel "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: @LeenaPatel its working now but its not getting the input id value